# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Python recursion

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

The question says:

> You are given an integer array coins representing coins of different denominations and >an integer amount representing a total amount of money.
> Return the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1.'

Here is what I am trying:

```
def coinChange(coins, amount, final_list=[]):
    """
    :type coins: List[int]
    :type amount: int
    :rtype: int
    """

    if all(coins) > amount:
        return -1
    while amount > 0:
        if amount - max(coins) >= 0:
            amount -= max(coins)
            final_list.append(max(coins))
        else:
            return coinChange(coins.remove(max(coins)), amount, final_list)

    return len(final_list)
coins = [1,2,5]
amount = 11
coinChange(coins, amount)
```

Can anybody help please

Comment: `if all(coins) > amount` is not correct. `all()` returns `True` or `False`, it makes no sense to compare that to `amount`.

Comment: You should not use mutable types as default arguments.  final_list=[] will not do what you want; do something like `final_list = None` and in the body do `if final_list is None: final_list = []`

Comment: Please post the full traceback so we easily see the error. And be advised, that `def coinChange(coins, amount, final_list=[]):` creates an empty list as the default for `final_list` and that list is always used as the default. All calls to `coinChange` using the default will append to that list.

Comment: `coins.remove` will not return a list.

Comment: `coins.remove(max(coins))` modifies the `coins` list in place and returns `None`. That's the reason for the error.

Comment: Don't be shy about adding print statements displaying the values you've calculated as you go. That's a good way to follow the flow of execution. Also, many IDEs have debuggers, they are great for this. Or go old school and use python's `pdb` line debugger.

Comment: Besides the above mentioned problems. For this `mini coin for change` the recursion is not very optimal, think about `DP`

Comment: Okay @DanielHao

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems mentioned in the comments, I'm not going to try to fix the rest of them.

The reason for the specific error you're getting is that `remove()` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return the modified list. So you're passing `None` as the `coins` argument when you make the recursive call.

So call `remove()` separately from the function call.

```
    else:
        coins.remove(max(coins))
        return coinChange(coins, amount, final_list)
```

Comment: This helped! that was a silly mistake on my part. Thanks a lot!